# Program terminating with 'std::out_of_range' basic_string::substr: __pos

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm writing a program for a class in which I have to pull strings with getline from a file, then print it out to a new file with one type of formatting. I am compiling just fine, but for some reason my program crashes even though I believe all my substr calls should be within the range of the strings. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>    
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct information{
    string first, middle, last, contribution;
    int birthyear;

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    information employee[1000];
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string input;
    int comma; //stores the location of the comma
    int space, space2, space3; //store the location of the spaces.
   int dollarsign; //checks where the dollar sign is and then the numbers                 after. 


fin.open("oldretirement.txt"); //opening input..
if (fin.fail()){
    fout<<"\nError! failed to open file!";
    exit(1);
}

fout.open("newretirement.txt");
if (fout.fail()){
    fout<<"\nError! failed to open file!";
    exit(1);
}
while(!fin.eof()){ //loops till file failure
    getline(fin, input);

    comma = input.find(",");

    if (isalpha(input[comma-1])){
        space = input.find(" "); //finds first space

        employee[i].last = input.substr(0, space-2);

        space2 = input.find(" ", space + 1); //finds the next space

        employee[i].first = input.substr(space+1, space2-space); //gets the substring of the area between spaces

        space3 = input.find(" ", space2+1); //you get the idea

        employee[i].middle = input.substr(space2+1, space3-space2);

        employee[i].birthyear = atoi((input.substr(space3+1, 4)).c_str());

        employee[i].contribution = input.substr(space3+5);
    }
    else{
        space = input.find(" ");

        employee[i].first = input.substr(0, space-1);

        space2 = input.find(" ", space+1);

        employee[i].middle = input.substr(space+1, space2-space);

        space3 = input.find(" ", space2+1);

        employee[i].last = input.substr(space2+1, space3-space2);

        employee[i].birthyear = atoi((input.substr(space3, 4)).c_str());

        dollarsign = input.find("$");

        employee[i].contribution = input.substr(dollarsign+2);
    }
    i++;
}
i--; //makes sure to make the number of indexes not too many.
int money_made; //something to save how much money they made the company other than a string, so that it is easier to compare.
string conversion; //something to store a string into to make things easier.
for (int j= 0;j<i;j++){ //looping for printing stuff
    fout<<employee[j].last<<", "<<employee[j].first<<" "<<employee[j].last<<" "<<employee[j].birthyear<<employee[j].contribution;

    conversion = employee[j].contribution;

    conversion.erase((conversion.find(","), 1)); //erases the comma to make conversion to int easier.

    money_made = atoi(conversion.c_str()); //converts string to integer

    int age = (2017 - employee[j].birthyear);
    if( (money_made > 300000)&&(age >= 60))
       fout<<" Ready\n"; //
    else
        fout<<endl;
}
fin.close();
fout.close();

}
```

And my input document is a text document with input lines like

Mary Johnson Smith 1953 $ 329,475

Smith, Mary Johnson 1953    329,475

Where I have to make my code adapt to the type and read it in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Find can fail.  You need to check that, especially since you're using `eof()` which is pretty much always wrong.  Use `while(getline(...))`.

Comment: I replaced my while(!fin.eof()) with while(getline(fin, input)) as you suggested, however I still am having issues. Also the point of this program is to only read those types of lines described above, so find should always return a space when looking for one and a dollar sign when I need to look for those.

Comment: As @RetiredNinja said, `while(!fin.eof())` is probably not doing what you expect. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/ states `Note that the value returned by this function depends on the last operation performed on the stream (and not on the next).` So `fin.eof()` is true **after** you read and hit EOF and not before.

Comment: Either your math on a substr is wrong, or find is failing.  Time to use a debugger.